# Asignar formato de número en un data frame

Tags: pandas

Necesito asignar el formato de número en un `data frame`, la columna 'paises euro' es una parte de la columna 'Totales' y 'countries'

**Código:**

```
 tabla.insert(4, 'Paises Euro', tabla['countries']/tabla['Totales'])
 tabla.insert(5, 'Rest of the World',1-tabla['Paises Euro'])
```

**Tabla:**

```
           Bad Words    good words  Totales countries   Paises Euro Rest of the World
   jul07    246500.0    16500.0   263000.0  23000.0     0.087452    0.912548
   jul08    7200.0       1200.0     8400.0    500.0     0.059524    0.940476
   jul10    28200.0      3000.0    31200.0   1000.0     0.032051    0.967949
   jul11    258000.0    42000.0   300000.0  19800.0     0.066000    0.934000
   jul12    240000.0    28200.0   268200.0  15600.0     0.058166    0.941834
```

Answer (score 1):

Cuando hablas del formato de número, entiendo que te refieres a la forma en que `pandas` muestra la información numérica. Esto lo puedes configurar de manera simple mediante `options.display.float_format`

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
txt=StringIO(""" "Bad Words"    "good words"  "Totales countries"   "Paises Euro" "Rest of the World"
    jul07    246500.0    16500.0   263000.0  23000.0     0.087452    0.912548
    jul08    7200.0       1200.0     8400.0    500.0     0.059524    0.940476
    jul10    28200.0      3000.0    31200.0   1000.0     0.032051    0.967949
    jul11    258000.0    42000.0   300000.0  19800.0     0.066000    0.934000
    jul12    240000.0    28200.0   268200.0  15600.0     0.058166    0.941834
""")
df = pd.read_csv(txt,  quotechar = '"', delim_whitespace=True)

pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

pd.options.display.float_format = '${:,.2f}'.format # Configuramos separadores de miles y 2 decimales

df
```

La salida:

```
                  Bad Words  good words  Totales countries  Paises Euro  Rest of the World
jul07 246,500.00  16,500.00  263,000.00          23,000.00         0.09               0.91
jul08 7,200.00     1,200.00    8,400.00             500.00         0.06               0.94
jul10 28,200.00    3,000.00   31,200.00           1,000.00         0.03               0.97
jul11 258,000.00  42,000.00  300,000.00          19,800.00         0.07               0.93
jul12 240,000.00  28,200.00  268,200.00          15,600.00         0.06               0.94
```